# Read data in NodeJS using cookies

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to read HTML page data in NodeJS using cookies below are the steps I have integrated into my file.

Get cookies from the first webpage.
Send cookies that got from step 1 and read the data based on it.

I have successfully written code to get cookies for step1 need some suggestions to send cookies using headers and read HTML page data.
Below is the code I have used but did not succeed.

```
request({
  uri: "WEB_PAGE_URL",
  method: "GET",
  header: {
        cookie: data
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('error');
    } else {
            console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Please suggest
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you will do it

```
var cookie = request.cookie('USERNAME=blahblah');

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': cookie
};

var options = {
    url: "WEB_PAGE_URL",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        //on success
    } else {
        //on error
    }
});
```